# Selenium Docker: Firefox crashes when trying to open fancybox popup

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using Selenium docker-compose with specs:

```
ubuntu instance: 16.04
firefox browser version is 61.0
selenium version is 3.13.0
geckodriver version is 0.21.0.
```

My docker-compose.yml file is as follows:

```
version: "3"
services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
```

I am running a test which has button, which upon clicking opens a popup. It is not an alert or another window. The thing is, when I try to click on that button, the browser seems to crash. with the following exceptions:

```
(/opt/firefox-latest/firefox:142): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create directory '/home/seluser/.cache/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.

[Parent 72, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error (52): Connection reset by peer: file /builds/worker/workspace/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 353

###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x16007F,name=PBrowser::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot send/recv

A content process crashed and MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_SHUTDOWN is set, shutting down
*** UTM:SVC TimerManager:registerTimer called after profile-before-change notification. Ignoring timer registration for id: telemetry_modules_ping
```

Further Info:

The HTML structure of the application which I am trying to access via selenium-docker is:

```
 <a id=some_id href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openPopup(true)" class="fancybox">
       <img src=some_src.svg class=some_class title>
</a>
```

I have accessed the element using xpath, class, css selector. I am not able to pinpoint the root cause of the issue. Is this browser related, or is this docker related or driver related?

UPDATE:
The stacktrace on my IDE is:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Tried to run command without establishing a connection
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:24:21.231Z'
System info: host: 'SOME_HOST', ip: 'SOME_IP', os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 61.0.1, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 255, moz:profile: /tmp/rust_mozprofile.IYBVxi..., moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, platformVersion: 4.4.0-1061-aws, rotatable: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, webdriver.remote.sessionid: 51c21208-100f-4a04-947c-3f9...}
Session ID: 51c21208-100f-4a04-947c-3f99316b75e7
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:605)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:448)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a fix for the problem.

I am trying to find a definitive reason for it but for now, the automation is working as it should. 
Couple things I added in the docker-compose.yml fixed the issues which are as follows:
In selenium-hub add:

```
environment:
      - GRID_BROWSER_TIMEOUT=30
```

In firefox add:

```
volumes:
      - "/dev/shm:/dev/shm"
```

Though its working I will still be looking for a logical explanation and if someone has it, would really appreciate if you posted it here.